# starting the app and a service from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

i try to start the app after the power disconnected from the phone and then start a service relating to camera

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED.equals((intent.getAction()))) {

        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

        intent = new Intent(context, CameraService.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startService(new Intent(context,CameraService.class));
        Toast.makeText(context, "black box activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        t.schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        context.stopService( new Intent(context,CameraService.class));
                        t.cancel();
                    }
                },
                3000);
    }
}
```

i am sure that the code for the camera service is correct,when i attempt to only open the activity or open the service it works, but when both it open the app and then crashes.any help?? thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post your log error.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.example.blackboxprototype01.CameraService@31962a78: java.lang.I Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
        at com.example.blackboxprototype01.CameraService.stopRecording(CameraService.java:150)
        at com.example.blackboxprototype01.CameraService.onDestroy(CameraService.java:133)llegalStateException , but if there is a problem with the service code why  does it run when i only start the service

Comment: so sorry i know the answer now , it was a problem of the delay time . the "IllegalStateException" means that the function that stops the service was invoked in inappropriate time, in my case i call it after 3 sec which wasnt enough for the service to be created in the first place , i increased the time and it worked , thanks a lot , and so sorry

Comment: you must post the log error on your question